# I need to create a input dialog box in visual C# or better suggestion?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am a college student taking a intro to programming C#. That being said,
We have created a form that asks for various input.
Once you click the "calculate" button, the program checks the input fields for correct format. If it is incorrect, it creates an error.
How would I create a input dialog box (like that of VB) without using a reference to VB?
Is this even an efficient way to accomplish this?
Is there a way to check input while it is being entered into the form, before clicking the "calculate" button?

I have spent a reasonable amount of time trying to solve this. I am not just jumping to ask a question.

Thanks for your help.

SUBCAN (maybe should be... subcan't... hehe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Windows Form with all the required input fields, you have a choice of using MaskedTextBox controls to validate or creating normal TextBox controls with ErrorProvider control (see below for links). Launch the form as a modal dialog box.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ErrorProviderComp.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984358(VS.71).aspx

Comment: I used the MaskedTextBox but was not able to completely figure out the whole ErrorProvider control. pretty confusing. Thank you for the input.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/GUI-Windows-Form/Adialogbyuserdefinedproperty.htm

the above link shows the complete code for a similar application.  It is the first link that popped up from googling "C sharp diablogbox".  Remember 'Google is your friend'.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Visual Studio Express.  Create a new Winforms C# application...That will give you what you need.  It will even start you off with a new form.  You won't need a reference to Visual Basic.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem quite elegantly with Windows Presentation Foundation.

The textbox in this example will only allow future dates

```
<TextBox Name="StartDateEntryForm" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" 
Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" 
Style="{StaticResource textStyleTextBox}" Margin="8,5,0,5">
<TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="StartDate" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
        Converter="{StaticResource dateConverter}" >
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <src:FutureDateRule />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_validation

(If you are planning on building more C# GUI's, I would highly recommend learning WPF. However, if this is a one-off application, the amount of time you would have to spend to learn WPF probably isn't worth it.)